# How many terms are required to get $D$ digits of Riemann zeta prime function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, estimation

How many terms are required to get $D$ digits of Riemann zeta prime function $\zeta_p(s) = \sum_p \frac{1}{p^s}$?

Sebah & Gourdon mentions that finding $\zeta_p(2)$ to 20 digits by using $\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2}$ directly would require computing all the primes upto $10^{20}$. So how did they get that?

Comment: That obviously depends on the used formula, Sebah & Gordon probably use simple summation of the inverse primes.
Henri Cohen gives a fast converging series in Section 2.1 of *High Precision Computation of Hardy-Littlewood Constants* (http://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~cohen/hardylw.dvi)

Comment: Sebah & Gordon too describes the series given by Cohen. Yes indeed @gammatester, $10^{20}$ terms are required if you use direct computation.

Answer (score 1):

From the prime number theorem, the density of primes around $n$ is asymptotically $1/\ln n$. So the convergence properties of the given series should be similar to those for $$\sum_n\frac1{n^s\ln n},$$ (summed over all natural numbers) and in particular, a reasonable approximation to the tail of the series will be the integral
$$\int_N^\infty\frac{dx}{x^s\ln x}.$$
Computing reasonable asymptotics for this integral is left as an exercise. ;-)

**Edit:** An upper bound is clearly $$\frac1{\ln N}\int_N^\infty\frac {dx}{x^s}=\frac{s-1}{N^{s-1}\ln N},$$ and this is probably not a bad estimate for $s=2$ since $x^2$ grows a lot faster than $\ln x$ does.

Now, to get accuracy $\varepsilon=10^{-20}$ for $s=2$, you need to solve $N\ln N=1/\varepsilon=10^{20}$.

Comment: @HeraldHanche-Olsen, is it $\frac{1}{n^s \ln n}$ or $\frac{1}{(n \ln n)^s}$? With prime number theorem $p_n \sim n \ln n$, I get $\frac{1}{(n \ln n)^s}$.

Comment: It's the former. The idea: Instead of summing over the prime numbers, imagine that you are summing over some random set of natural numbers, where $n$ has probability $1/\ln n$ of belonging to the set. Then take the expected value of the sum, and you get the sum I wrote up. (I fixed a misprint: The density is $1/\ln n$, not $\ln n$, clearly.)

Comment: Thanks, got it. Any idea if the same reasoning will hold with the alternating counterpart?

Comment: Often, the best way to handle an alternating series is to join the terms up in pairs, resulting in a positive series that can then be handled with this sort of reasoning.